# SQL - How do I implement one many-to-many table connecting to two tables?

Tags: sql, class-diagram

I have two tables, Student and Lecturer. Both Student and Lecturer have a many-to-many relationship with a table, User_Preferences as shown below.
[image: Class Diagram with many-to-many relationship]

However, is it even the correct implementation of foreign key as shown from the red arrow?

(Edited)I did try doing inheritance so that I can use user_id as the foreign key, however the question does not allow it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use one Users table and either differentiate between students and lecturers with a field in it, or have lecturers and students associated with it with individual tables. The latter is probably a better fit, though there is nothing in the schema above that necessarily requires it.

One scenario you should consider is if a user is both a student or a lecturer, which is not uncommon at third level. In this case they might have different details for each role.

The association table would then have user_id, preferences_id and optionally user_preference_id.

Comment: Wish I could do it, unfortunately I can't merge the tables under Users.

Comment: Strange. In that case, use separate association tables for lecturer/preferences and student/preferences.

Comment: Is it ok if I separate the bridge table to two, Lecturer_Preferences and Student_Preferences and have different Preferences table (the one at the bottom)? Or can they share the same Preferences table since the attributes are the same?

Comment: Use one preferences table.